# Passing a function as a prop with different parameter types in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am trying to pass a function that updates state in React, however VSCode is warning me of a typing issue. The error is `Type '(value: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: string | number) => void'. Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible. Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.` or `Type '(value: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: string | number) => void'. Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible. Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

This is within this code block:

```
<DropDownSelect
        options={blogTags}
        selectedOption={selectedBlogTag}
        allPosition="top"
        updateFunc={updateSelectedBlogTag}
      />
      <DropDownSelect
        options={["5", "10", "20", "50"]}
        selectedOption={selectedArticleCount}
        hideAll={true}
        updateFunc={updateArticleCount}
      />
```

DropDownSelect has the following interface:

```
interface IDropDownSelect {
  options: string[];
  selectedOption: string | number;
  hideAll?: boolean;
  allPosition?: "top" | "bottom";
  updateFunc: (value: string | number) => void;
}
```

I have the following context:

```
export interface IBlogListContextData {
  blogList: IBlogListData[];
  blogListPage: number;
  setBlogListPage: (page: number) => void;
  updateBlogListPage: (page: number) => void;
  isLoading: boolean;
  fetchBlogList: (page?: number) => void;
  blogTags: string[];
  selectedBlogTag: string;
  selectedArticleCount: number;
  updateArticleCount: (value: number) => void;
  updateSelectedBlogTag: (value: string) => void;
}

export const blogListContextDefaultValue: IBlogListContextData = {
  blogList: [blogListDefault],
  blogListPage: 1,
  setBlogListPage: () => null,
  updateBlogListPage: (page: number) => null,
  isLoading: false,
  fetchBlogList: () => null,
  blogTags: [],
  selectedBlogTag: "all",
  selectedArticleCount: 5,
  updateArticleCount: (value: number) => null,
  updateSelectedBlogTag: (value: string) => null,
};
```

Is there a way that I can pass either function in to `updateFunc` with either a string or number type? I am trying to avoid resorting to using `any`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can reuse the updateFunc type.

```
updateSelectedBlogTag: IDropDownSelect['updateFunc']
```

Comment: Not sure why but its still not working, it still says

Type '(value: number) => null' is not assignable to type '(value: string | number) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

And a variant with string as the type